# How to show ajax-loader each time when an iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I have seen many ajax loader which shows until an iframe finishes loading.But my question is there anyway I could show an ajax loader each time the content inside the iframe loads?

Example:

If I loaded a webpage in an iframe,it shows the loader.But after it been loaded,I clicked on another link inside the iframe webpage and when the page inside the iframe is loading it should show the loader again.

Is there anyway I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Dear You can show the loaded by adding a div on parent page and create a javascript function on parent page and then call that function from iframe using parent.methodonpareentpage
Parent Page

```
    <iframe id="iframe" src="url" style="height:600px; width:700px; display:none;"></iframe>
<div id="divIframeLoader" style="height:600px; width:700px;">
<img src="Images/loading_async_big.gif" style="position:relative; top:12%; left:40%;" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showIframeLoader(btrue) 
{
if (btrue) 
{
jQuery("#divIframeLoader").show();
jQuery("#iframe").hide();
}
else {
jQuery("#divIframeLoader").hide();
 jQuery("#iframe").show();
 }
}
</script>

iframe page
parent.showIframeLoader(true);
```